# Find out if a many to many relation includes an entity

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I am currently developing an API to handle surveys. The problem i am facing is, that i need to find out if for a given survey, a given user is able to moderate it. I have setup a many to many relationship between the two entities.

The request is handled as follows:
User sends a request to the server, which is validated by a token which also gives me the users id, as well as their email address. The request is then taken by a route, which takes the id of the survey as an input. I already get the "real" user and survey from the database and store them in their own variables. Now i just need a way to find out if the user appears on the moderator list of the survey.

Edit regarding some comments:
The question is how can i get this done? I really have no idea since user.moderates (name of the relation on the user side) and survey.moderators (inverse side of the relation) are not listed when getting the Entities from the database.

So basically i need a way to get all moderators of a survey and check if the given user is included in this list

Code in the request:

```
user = await getUser(res.locals.keycloakId);
if (user === null)
{
    res.status(404).json({error: "User does not exist"});
}
else
{
    survey = getSurveyById(+req.params['id'];
    if (survey === null)
    {
        res.status(404).json({error: "Survey does not exist"});
    }
    else
    {
        if (!await hasAccess(user, survey))
        {
            res.status(403).json({error: "User is not allowed to access this survey"});
        }
    }
}
```

Now the hasAccess function should return whether or not the user is on the moderators list of the survey, currently it looks like this:

```
export async function hasAccess(user: User, survey: Survey): Promise<boolean>
{
    if (// check if user has access to that survey)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) There is no question, so not sure what you need our help with. 2) There is no code in your post, so we cannot add to it or fix it.

Comment: 1) the question is, how do i get this done 2) there is no code because i have no idea how to achieve it, that is also the reason why i am asking

Comment: You will have to post the models for `User` and `Survey` as the answer depends on how the moderators/moderates relation is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant solution but i managed to find one. By requesting the survey again, this time filtering for relations it is possible to just check if the result is null.

Something like this:

```
export async function hasAccess(user, survey)
{
    let relations = await Survey.findOneBy({
        moderators: user,
        id: survey.id,
    });
return relations !== null;
}
```